# How to access the Local FTP YUM repo from client Machine

Tags: rhel, yum, ftp

I setup the FTP server on Machine A 192.168.1.105 and created the YUM repo. And placed following contents in it.

```
#vi rhel-localftp.repo

[rhel-localftp.rep]
name=bla bla bla
baseurl=file:///var/ftp/pub/Server(RPMs are under Server folder)
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
```

then installed httpd everything worked fine on Machine A.

Now turn of Machine B 192.168.1.106

I created the repository to access the RPMs from Machine A and contents are

```
#vi remoteftp.repo

[rhel-remoteftp.rep]
name=bla bla bla
baseurl=ftp://192.168.1.105/var/ftp/pub/Server
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
```

and then i tried to install package and it gave me this error

Note: There is no Firewall in between them

[image]

Do i have to install FTP server also on Machine B

Comment: Do you have `repodata/repmod.xml` in `Server` directory?

Comment: Yes it is there.... /etc/ftp/pub/Server/repodata/repmod.xml

Comment: Is the FTP server started on machine A?

Comment: Damn, something is wrong with FTP server itself. It was running but when I restarted everything started working.

Answer (score 2):

Since default home directory for ftp is /var/ftp/pub so there is no need to provide "/var/ftp" in "baseurl" parameter.

```
baseurl=ftp://192.168.1.105/var/ftp/pub/Server  # WRONG

baseurl=ftp://192.168.1.105/pub/Server          # Correct
```

Also make sure , you are able to connect ftp server , so you can just check using `ftp server-ip` to check connectivity.

Comment: Ok this time i just used **baseurl=ftp://192.168.1.105/pub/Server** but got the same error

Comment: are you able to browse same ftp url from your browser in client end ?

Comment: No not even from Browser. I tried both ftp://192.168.1.105 and ftp://192.168.1.105/pub/Server but no use

Comment: Rahul, there was problem with the FTP server itself I restarted it now its working. But thanks for giving me correct information about baseurl and how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried [yum-pull](http://www.stearns.org/mirror/yum-pull-setup.html) it might work.

Comment: Please avoid [link-only answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65277/are-link-only-answers-poor-practice). Provide enough context to answer the question. Furthermore, `yum-pull` is a tool for mirroring repositories, while according to the question, the OP wants machine A to function as the package source for machine B, not mirror the repository on B. The error message in the screenshot and the comments indicate the problem was with the FTP configuration on machine A. How exactly would `yum-pull` help in this case?

Answer (score 0):

```
[rhel-remoteftp.rep]
name=bla bla bla
baseurl=ftp://192.168.1.105/var/ftp/pub/Server
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
```

please change the `[rhel-remoteftp]` instead of `[rhel-remoteftp.rep]`

Then try let me know..........

Answer (score -1):

SElinux should be enforced to 0 at server side.

Also flush firewall if nothing happens...

```
setenforce 0
iptables -F
```